# How to convert Date with TimeZone format to normal Date?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

**Existing Date:** 2017-08-03T18:30:00.000Z

**Required Date:** DD-MMM-YY

I tried this :

```
var d = 2017-08-03T18:30:00.000Z; 
var newd = moment.parseZone(d).format("DD-MMM-YY");
```

But newd returns a previous date.

Basically, I'm inserting date from datepicker into a MongoDB. 
I'm inserting date in this format 08/07/2017 into the database which has date variable schema type as Date.

When I retrieve the date I'm getting the date in the above format from database.
(2017-08-03T18:30:00.000Z)

Looks like I haven't elaborated my question. 
I'm binding the variable from DataTable

```
 var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: false,
    "aoColumnDefs": [ { "sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [ 0 ], visible: false } ], // first column in visible columns array gets class "hide_me"
    ajax: {
        url: "/getData",
        dataSrc: "list"
    },
    columns: [
        { data : "_id"},
        { data : "user.name" },
        { data : "date", render: function(d){
            return moment.parseZone(d).format("DD-MMM-YY");
        } },

   ],
 });
```

Comment: Use d = "2017-08-03T18:30:00.000Z"; missing quotation

Comment: @EmdadulSawon Nope that doesn't work.

Comment: Works with the right quotes for me: https://jsfiddle.net/cuzq99yk/

Comment: You need to post (minimal) code that reproduces the issue. If the string is quoted, the code works as expected (i.e. it generates a string "03-Aug-17").

Answer (score 1):

You just missed quotation. I have tried following and it works

```js
var d = "2017-08-03T18:30:00.000Z";
var newd = moment.parseZone(d).format("DD-MMM-YY");
console.log(newd);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Also at [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXRgKV)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Anirudh you used moment is good now try moment timezone 
https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

by moment timezone you can change timezone

convert GST to your local timezone then formate date

Get local timezone By: var ltz =  moment.tz.guess();

Now convert: moment.tz(date, ltz).format('DD-MMM-YY');